# Change color and backgroud color,Tint

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a collection view, I want that selected item will change the background and color of the image. Please help

Comment: Change selected item color https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#change-selected-item-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name of you collection view is `MyCollectionView`, then you can simply do this:

```
MyCollectionView.ItemTemplate = MyCollectionView.ItemTemplate.WithSelectedBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
```

There's other ways of doing this as you can see here:

- [Using C# code](https://github.com/hartez/SelectedItemStyling/blob/master/SelectedItemStyling/SelectedItemStyling/CodeOnly.cs)
- [Using XAML](https://github.com/hartez/SelectedItemStyling/blob/master/SelectedItemStyling/SelectedItemStyling/WithStyle.xaml)